# How to pass strings from class to another in wxPython

Tags: string, class, wxpython

I want to pass string self.dirname and self.filename from this class:

```
    class Class1(wx.Frame):
def __init__(self,parent,id):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, 'Class1', size=(300,600))
    wx.Frame.CenterOnScreen(self)

    self.dirname = ""
    dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Vyber súbor", self.dirname, "", "*.*", wx.OPEN)
    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        self.filename=dlg.GetFilename()
        self.dirname=dlg.GetDirectory()
        dlg.Close()
```

To this class:

```
    class GERPYFrame(wx.Frame):
def __init__(self,parent,id):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, 'GERPY Compiler', size=(300,600))
```

I was triyng this for hours and yes, i have find something about this, but any of codes, what i have tried weren´t working with my code. Can somebody help please, i really don´t know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `self.dirname` and `self.filename` as class `GERPYFrame` constructor's parameters:

```
class GERPYFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, dirname, filename):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, 'GERPY Compiler', size=(300,600))
        self.dirname = dirname
        self.filename = filename
```